# Execute angular directive only if parent event is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive which works lovely, if I use it just like an attribute tag.  Now I want to execute it, only if the the form validation in my controller is done.

My directive code is:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function ($location) {
'use strict';

return {
  restrict: 'A',
  replace: false,
  scope: {
    'myDirective': '@'

  },

  link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

    initialize();

    /* initialize -
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
    function initialize() {

        createEventListeners();

    }

    /* createEventListeners -
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
    function createEventListeners() {
      // listen for a click
      $element.on('click', function () {
        // set the hash like a normal anchor scroll
        $location.hash($scope.myDirective);

        // smooth scroll to the passed in element
        scrollTo($scope.myDirective);
      });
    }.... etc.
```

And my HTML is:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-step" data-my-directive="ats" data-ng-click="stepone.$valid && saveStepOne()" type="submit">Next</button>
```

The directive is for smooth scrolling to some anchor block on the page...

 And `data-my-directive='ats'` actually just add in the url bar `#ats` and start scrolling. But my idea is:

I want to start scrolling **only if** the "stepOne" is valid and save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-if="isParentDone">
  <div my-directive....>
```

`ng-if` will actually add/remove the html elements to the DOM, so your initialization functions will only be called when they are actually created.

Sidenote: I see you have an `$element.on('click')`. You really should be using `ng-click` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer doesn't help me so much. First - I can't use "ng-if" like a wrapper, because as you may see, I use "submit" button to submit/send some data, and then to slide to next "frame". Second - I can't use "ng-click", because there have such event already for checking the validation of the form and start some function.

Comment: @FireBull I don't understand your points. Whats wrong with wrapping your submit? And why cant you just add to the `ng-click`?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe is my English... Because if I wrap the submit button with ng-if - I'll hide the button until the condition is not done. And about the ng-click - there already have such.

Comment: @FireBull If you don't want the logic to run, you might as well not show the button. And my point with the `ng-click` is that you can still just add to those functions.